# how to connect wlan0

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I had wifi connection on Ubuntu 16.04 with no problems, but now it is off and wlan0 status is "disconnected".  What command or shortcut should I use to get wifi going again?

Comment: Could you check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), and the output to yours. Use http://pastebin.com if it is too long.

Answer (score 0):

To turn wlan0 on, in a terminal type:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: Thanks Doudou, should I reboot, because wlan0 is still disconnected ?

Comment: No normally not. Can you provide with the last apt log (the one from today) doing `gedit /var/log/apt/history.log`?

Comment: Sorry,  but this command "gedit /var/log/apt/history.log" returns a blank page.

Comment: mhmh that's weird. Anyway stupid question but, do you have by any chance on your keyboard a wifi key? On mine F12 is actually assigned to switch on/off the wlan card

Comment: I do not know about that key, I have a recent HP Pavillion with a 17" screen, but I will try the f12 right now

Comment: The f12 key did turn on and off the check mark besides "activate wifi network".  Now I will check if wlan0 is still off.  Back in a sec.

Comment: Wlan0 sill disconnected.  I have to leave for a while, but I will be back shortly.  We will keep trying to solve this one.

Comment: I will be in and out from now on, but if you come up with any other suggestions feel free to post them and I will get back to you a.s.a.p.

Comment: Hi, is anyone able to help with my wlan0 being disconnected?  Suggestions made by Doudou could have been helpful but I am still with ''wlan0 disconnected'' problem.  Thanks